# How is the alignment of the physical memory guaranteed?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-alignment

malloc() returns a memory suitably aligned for any in-built type. In cases where more specific alignment is required (like 16 or 32 bytes) it can be done at the application level. But this alignment is at the virtual memory level.

How is it guaranteed that the underlying physical memory is also at the same alignment ?

Comment: Virtual memory pages are always aligned to physical memory pages, because of the way VM works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual memory is implemented at the page level, so every VM page maps to a physical memory page when it's loaded into memory. So everything more finely grained than the page will also be aligned equivalently between virtual and physical memory.

Comment: I guess the question then becomes how is it guaranteed that a 4 byte aligned start address of a VM page is also 4 byte aligned at the physical memory and not 2 bytes aligned ? Is it done by the VM subsystem of the kernel ?

Comment: Memory pages are a power of 2 in size, typically 1024 or 4096 bytes. Since that's a multiple of 4, anything that's 4-byte aligned in VM will also be 4-byte aligned in PM.