# Do SIMD instructions require data to be aligned?

Tags: memory, vectorization, simd, virtual-memory, memory-alignment

I'm confused with logical and physical memory alignments.

To use vector instructions efficiently such as AVX and SSE, we may need data to be aligned.

Does this say that data aligned in virtual memory is also aligned properly in physical memory?

If yes, how does the compiler do the good job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the alignment of the physical memory guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579441/how-is-the-alignment-of-the-physical-memory-guaranteed)

Comment: Not *required*; modern x86 CPUs handle misalignment pretty efficiently.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other guides.  It helps significantly for AVX512 though where a vector is the same width as a cache line, so any misalignment means every load or store will be a cache-line split, not just every other or every fourth.  You can look at compiler output on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: I think I see what you're asking: whether an aligned virtual address is also an aligned physical address.  (Yes, for alignments up to the page size, which is much larger than the SIMD vector width.)  But that's totally different from the question title.  Pick one question and edit the title or body to match the other.